# how to solve error installer (built) vb.net 2017

Tags: vb.net, build, installation

i have a problem when try to make installer (build) vb.net 2017, i get error massage "The following files may have dependencies that cannot be determined automatically. please confirm that all dependencies have been added to the project. c:\windows\system32\macromedia\flash\flash.ocx"

what should i do

Comment: Add it to the installer project?

Comment: It appears that your application is using Flash Player.  That means that your application will not work on systems that don't have Flash installed.  You would need to inform your users of that and tell them that they must install Flash if it isn't already installed or else create a perquisite package for Flash yourself and include it in your installer.

Comment: You might want to re-evaluate the use of Flash because it is being deprecated at the end of 2020: [Adobe blog article](https://theblog.adobe.com/adobe-flash-update/); [Adobe Finally Kills Flash Dead](https://www.wired.com/story/adobe-finally-kills-flash-dead/).